# jquery slideToggle with this selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I have a problem with with jquery slideToggle, here is my code:

```js
$(".dropdownmainmenu").click(function(){
  $(this).children(".showmenu").slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("activemainmenu");
  $(this).find(".showarrowmainmenu").toggleClass("arrowright");
  $(this).find(".showarrowmainmenu").toggleClass("arrowdown");
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdownmainmenu">
  <div class="hedmainmenu">
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i>
      News
      <span class="showarrowmainmenu arrowright"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="showmenu">
    <li><a href="add_news.php">Add news</a></li>
    <li><a href="news.php">All News</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

My problem is when I slide down the menu and try to open link like *Add news* it doesn't work and the menu slide up.

How can i fix this problem?

Comment: Please add a JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If understand right you want to addEventListener only to the `div` element with class `.hedmainmenu`:

```js
//change the selector to add eventListener to the the div with class hedmainmenu
$(".dropdownmainmenu > div.hedmainmenu").click(function() {
  //now .showmenu is sibling of div.hedmainmenu so I used .next()
  $(this).next(".showmenu").slideToggle();
  $(this).toggleClass("activemainmenu");
  $(this).find(".showarrowmainmenu").toggleClass("arrowright");
  $(this).find(".showarrowmainmenu").toggleClass("arrowdown");
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdownmainmenu">
  <div class="hedmainmenu">
    <a href="#">
      <i class="fa fa-newspaper-o"></i> News <span class="showarrowmainmenu arrowright"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <ul class="showmenu">
    <li><a href="add_news.php">Add news</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="news.php">All News</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```